# Reading embedded objects from presentation using python

Tags: python-2.7, python-pptx

I am working on python-pptx module. I have a presentation file which contains embedded files like(.pptx, .xlsx, .docx, .pdf) on slides. I need to read those files also while parsing the presentation.

Is there any python-pptx attribute to read those embedded files.

I tried to get the 'shape_type' for those embedded files but it is giving 'none' while in 'shape.name' it is giving 'Object 5'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that there is no API support for embedded files. You're on your own for doing that with `python-pptx`, at least so far.

A chart object interacts with an embedded Excel file (.xlsx), so reviewing the code for that might give you some ideas, but it would be a serious development exercise.